# Don't understand if/else behavior within for loop

Tags: python, oop, object, if-statement, for-loop

So I have a object with a method that is supposed to iterate over a list which is defined in the class.

When I use a simple if statement, I get the expected result, however, when I add an else statement I get strange results.

```
Class SomeClass(object):
     def __init__(self):
          self.config = ['something', 'this exists', 'some more stuff']

     def check_this(self):
          for line in self.config:
               if "this exists" in line:
                    return True
```

The above code returns True as soon as I get to the 2nd element in the list.

If I change the code to the following.  The method returns False.

```
Class SomeClass(object):
     def __init__(self):
          self.config = ['something', 'this exists', 'some more stuff']

     def check_this(self):
          for line in self.config:
               if "this exists" in line:
                    return True
               else:
                    return False
```

I have to be missing something here.
Python 2.7.6 on MAC OS X

Comment: You **always** return inside the first iteration of your loop. You return with either `True` or `False`, based *solely* on the first line. Think about that for a while, then try and think about when the `return False` should be executed instead.

Answer (score 5):

In your latter case you never hit the 2nd element, because the 1st returns `False`. A function can only `return` one time.

In your first method, the only time it will return is if it get into your `if` block and will return `True`. If it never gets into the `if` block, it will return `None`.

In your second method, in the very first iteration,`'this exists'` is not in `line` so it returns `False` and stops iterating.

If I understand the intention of that function, it could simply be

```
def check_this(self):
    return "this exists" in self.config
```

Comment: ARGH!  So obvious!  Thanks Cory.  I feel stupid now.  Should have seen that.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
 Class SomeClass(object):
      def __init__(self):
           self.config = ['something', 'this exists', 'some more stuff']

      def check_this(self):
          if "this exists" in self.config:
              return True
          else:
              return False
```